# Make the [cshrc] tag a synonym for [csh]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I just noticed the existence of the [cshrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cshrc) tag, with no usage guidance or tag wiki and (currently) 22 questions tagged as such.

The `.cshrc` file is simply one of two startup files that are read when a C shell starts, and I can’t think of any reason why it should exist independently of [csh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csh). For comparison, the [bashrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) tag is (quite sensibly) already a synonym for [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash).

Personally, as a Bash user, I don’t have an answer score of 5 or more on this tag, so I can’t suggest tag synonyms. I figured posting here would be the next best thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I retagged those handful of questions to [csh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csh).

I don't think we need a synonym. It's a fairly low-activity tag, and now that it's been removed I strongly doubt it'll be re-created again.

Comment: Nice one. Is there usually a delay in removing tags? When I tried using it just now https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22557602/revisions, the tag was still available for use.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Yeah, there's some caching. Try again tomorrow.